Terraform dynamic block for GCP firestore
I'm trying to create a module for GCP firestore that creates a single database which can create multiple indexes with multiple fields but am having some trouble.
I've tried with for_each but I don't know how to do it exactly. I need the collection (from the index) name and the fields to be dynamic together.
This is my code so far:
main.tf (module)
resource "google_firestore_database" "database" {
 project                           = var.project_id
 name                              = var.firestore_name
 location_id                       = var.firestore_location_id
 type                              = var.firestore_type
 concurrency_mode                  = var.firestore_concurrency_mode
 app_engine_integration_mode       = var.firestore_app_engine_integration_mode
 point_in_time_recovery_enablement = var.firestore_point_in_time_recovery_enablement
 delete_protection_state           = var.firestore_delete_protection_state
 # deletion_policy                   = var.firestore_deletion_policy
}

resource "google_firestore_index" "my-index" {
 project    = var.project_id
 database   = var.firestore_name
 collection = var.firestore_collection

 fields {
   field_path = var.firestore_field_path
   order      = var.firestore_order
 }
 fields {
   field_path = var.firestore_field_path
   order      = var.firestore_order
 }
}

I have tried this:
resource "google_firestore_index" "catalog-dev" {
 project    = google_firestore_database.database.project
 database   = google_firestore_database.database.name
 collection = var.firestore_collection

 dynamic "fields" {
   for_each = var.indexfieldvars
   content {
     field_path = fields.value.field_path
     order      = fields.value.order
   }
 }
}

variable "indexfieldvars" {
   type = list(object({
       field_path = string
       order = string
   }))
}

variable "firestore_collection" {
   type = string
}

But I need the collection to be related to the specific fields.
I've read on nested dynamic blocks, but I'm not sure if that works for my case.

What is var.indexfieldvars? Can you add that to the question as well?

Adding var.firestore_collection would also be beneficial.

Added the definition of the variables as requested @MarkoE

Well, what I would probably do is try to create a variable of type map which would then somehow map between the collection and the fields.

Solution 1
If collections are known beforehand you can add a condition in the for_each statement and make as many dynamic blocks as collections that you know of:
resource "google_firestore_index" "catalog-dev" {
  project    = google_firestore_database.database.project
  database   = google_firestore_database.database.name
  collection = var.firestore_collection


  dynamic "fields" {
    for_each = var.firestore_collection == "collection1" ? var.indexfieldvars : []
    content {
      field_path = fields.value.field_path
      order      = fields.value.order
    }
  }

  dynamic "fields" {
    for_each = var.firestore_collection == "collection2" ? var.indexfieldvars : []
    content {
      field_path = fields.value.field_path
      order      = fields.value.order
    }
  }
  
  # More dynamic blocks if needed

}

Solution 2
If collections are not known beforehand, as @Marko E suggests, create a variable that will map collections with fields. Then use for_each at a resource level and inside a dynamic block.
Variable:
variable "firestore_collections_with_fields" {
  type = map(object({
    fields = list(object({
      field_path = string
      order      = string
    }))
  }))
  default = {
    collection1 = {
      fields = [
        {
          field_path = "field_path0",
          order      = "order"
        },
        {
          field_path = "field_path1",
          order      = "order"
        }
      ]
    },
    collection2 = {
      fields = [
        {
          field_path = "field_path2",
          order      = "order"
        },
        {
          field_path = "field_path3",
          order      = "order"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Resource:
resource "google_firestore_index" "catalog-dev" {
  for_each = var.firestore_collections_with_fields

  project  = google_firestore_database.database.project
  database = google_firestore_database.database.name

  collection = each.key

  dynamic "fields" {
    for_each = each.value.fields
    content {
      field_path = fields.value.field_path
      order      = fields.value.order
    }
  }
}


Collections are not known and can have complex names. Instead, I can create a list with objects containing the fields as a list and the collection name as a string.

So my second solution seems to address your use case.
